# Servlets and html issue

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am attempting to learn how to use a querystring. My goal is to modify a servlet and from that be able to pull data from a querystring in my URL. I specifically need to show the "action". My URL querystring is to be entered as 
`?param1=val1&param2=val2`. I attempted to modify my servlets `processRequest` with the following line:

```
out.println("<p>" + request.getParameter("<p> Action is"  [value] "</p>") +</p>);
```

Any ideas of where to go from here? I'm getting several errors.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `processRequest` `several errors`. Paste the errors here and the servlet code that is accepting the request

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving invalid values from the request parameters.
More specifically, based on your querystring you should retrieve the parameters `param1` and `param2`, which will contain values `val1` and `val2` respectively, like so:

```
String p1 = request.getParameter("param1");
String p2 = request.getParameter("param2");
System.out.println("params: 1:"+p1+" 2:"+p2);
```